# Is there a way to add more options to the Custom Task Pane Options Menu Via VSTO?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, customtaskpane

I have a [custom task pane](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx) in MS Word. I want to add a few more options to the options menu i.e.the arrow next to the cross button that has the move and close options. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not supported. Put a control on the task pane surface as part of the content you define for the task pane.

Comment: Ok. If there are no options. I wish it were there. Those are context options the users got to by default. Great place to have a link to launch a settings dialog and the sign out of cloud service link.